# 好羡慕拍照的人，有这么漂亮的人可以拍: who is 的人?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, sentence-structure

Google translated this 好羡慕拍照的人，有这么漂亮的人可以拍 as
“I really envy people who take pictures. There are such beautiful people who can take pictures.”

Context:  This came from someone looked at some pictures of one person.

I thought it implied the person whose pictures were taken.

Am I wrong?

Comment: To specifically answer the question, ("who is 的人"), answer, the first 的人 is the photographer, and the second 的人 are the photographic subjects.

Comment: Perhaps you were misled by the clumsy phrase 可以拍, which you interpret as " who can take pictures" It should, in the context of the whole sentence, be read as "who have their pictures taken"

Comment: @Wayne Cheah.   I agreed with you on this.  If you would put it in the answer, I will select it as the answer.

Comment: There is no real need to formalize my comment. Your response is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the context you provided, that sentence should mean something like this:

> I envy the one who took this photo, because s/he could take a photo of such a gorgeous.

的人 = the one who took the picture, i.e. the photographer.

Full version:

> [我]好羡慕拍[这张]照的人, [他/她]有这么漂亮的人可以拍

Implied meaning [not accurate at all]:

> I am so jealous that someone could befriend with this beautiful lady/handsome man.

Or even worse:

> Wow, it is so lucky to be a friend with this gorgeous, aka me ;) [provided that the person in that photo is herself/himself] [This is so pretentious of course, totally a show-off ]

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Comment: May I ask what software did you use to do the translation of the last two.

Comment: @EmilyJ I am native. These last two scenarios are totally imagined. Of course these are not solely translations. They are not accurate, as I claimed

Answer (score 2):

1. The latter half of your sentence belongs to the structure `subject + 有 + object + transitive verb`, where the subject `拍照的人` is hidden. To understand why they are arranged like so, consider a simpler example below.
2. When we rearrange `我吃東西` ('I eat something'), which bears the orthodox `subject + verb + object` structure, into `我有東西吃` ('I have something to eat'), the sentence gravitates towards the object `東西` (i.e. food). The purpose of saying `我有東西吃` is that there is food to eat, not eating itself.
3. Similarly, `拍照的人/有/人/可以拍` (for simplicity, remove the adjectival phrase `這麼漂亮的`) is `拍照的人/可以拍/人` rearranged (lit. ‘people who take pictures=the photographer can take someone’s picture’). `有人可以拍` emphasises on the fact that there does exist *someone* that a photographer (the hidden subject) can take pictures of, not the action itself.
4. In `我有東西吃`, we may guess by emphasising on the food, the speaker might have been hungry for a long while. In `拍照的人有人可以拍`, we may guess, by the emphasis on (the beauty) of photographic models, the reason of the speaker's envy. The point being, common sense does help in parsing sentences correctly.
5. Google translation thinks a noun (`有人`) placed before a verb (`可以拍`, lit. can take) must make it the doer of the verb, following the logic in `SVO` structure. That is not the case, because the structure is rearranged.

Answer (score 2):

好羡慕[*那些*]拍照的人，有这么漂亮的人[*供(讓)他們*]拍[*攝*].

While the translation is understandable, the modified sentence above is more likely to be the comment heard from a Chinese tongue/audience, at a fashion show, or a photographic event.

Comment: There is a fundamental error in the latter half of Google's translation regarding the grammatical subject of the sentence. The translation should not be thought as being 'understandable'. Rectifiable, but not understandable.

Comment: @L Parker It is not a good translation, but I don't think google is to be blamed 100%, the source is important too. On this case, the sentence is understandable by most Chinese people. .

Comment: Rather contradictory to the spirit of translation, no?

Comment: @L Parker I don't want to guess/comment something I didn't see. But remember "garbage in, garbage out" could be the case. I've no mean to protect google though.

Comment: Normally I would agree with you, but I think we should make clear that the translation is problematic (specifically, grammatically incongruent to the original sentence) to *language learners*.

Comment: @ L Parker I haven't tried google translation for a complete sentence yet, so I couldn't comment on its accuracy. Maybe you can give it a try, and see the outcome. But don't expect too much out of a low level robot :)

Comment: The translation of the second clause is simply inaccurate: "有这么漂亮的人可以拍" DOES NOT translate into "There are such beautiful people who can take pictures." An accurate translation is "There are such beautiful people to pictures of." The "的人" in this clause refers to the photographed models, not the photographers.

Comment: @monalisa The reason for that inaccuracy is, IMO, mainly due to the poor sentence been translated. Let's erase the word "who" from the translated sentence "There are such beautiful people who can take pictures." , the translation then almost matches the source sentence in one to one relationship. Bad, yes, but with reasons.

Comment: @r13 First of all, the OP does a google translation of a perfectly grammatical, and acceptable sentence, and then wonders whether that translation is correct or not. To say that the translation is understandable implies that it is accurate. I do not agree. That translation is inaccurate. That was all I was trying to say.

Comment: @r13 You suggest that we erase the word "who" from the translated sentence "There are such beautiful people who can take pictures.". If we do that, the sentence becomes *There are such beautiful people can take pictures. - which is ungrammatical. So I do not understand what your point is.

Comment: @monalisa That's the point, the robot can't, or not programed smart enough, to guess the meaning, but to translate word by word with some effort (which I don't know how/what) to make the translated sentence grammatically correct. I am not a language scholar, but in this case, I could say it is all started with the poor grammar of the input (the original sentence in Chinese), which has caused the inaccuracy, because in no way the machine can think or guess.

Comment: @monalisa Note that "understandable" doe not mean the translation is "accurate". For instance, when a foreigner speak to you with poorly composed/lousy English, many times you may find it is understandable, but inaccurate in the sense of grammar, or local costume. Sorry, if I've confused you again.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone may take a photo, so it seems a somewhat strange thing to say.

好羡慕拍照的人，有这么漂亮的人可以拍。

好羡慕那些摄影师，有这么漂亮的人可以拍摄！
I really envy those photographers, they have such gorgeous people to snap shots of.

"Beauty's only skin deep, you're just as pretty as you feel inside"